# How to modify object parsed from a sample JSON body then use that object to append properly in JSON builder?

Tags: json, groovy, katalon-studio

While trying to parse the sample JSON body and modify that object according to my preference, I'm having trouble appending it to the existing JSON body that it came from initially. The problem is that when I append it the previous object in array also changed according to the newest object that I modified.

I have tried multiple ways to append it to the existing body and trying to modify a copy of the object but ultimately results in the same problem. I think I'm missing something important and I'm quite new in JS/Groovy Script

```
Col fromCurr 
row 1 = EUR
row 2 = CAD
```

```
int rows = rateCurrencyList.getRowNumbers() /* not being used yet to iterate to all records */
def saveDiffRateSetJsonBody = '''[
    {
        "fromcurrency": "EUR",
        "invConvRate": "1.09",
        "convRate": "1",
        "sourceCode": "MANUAL",
        "tocurrency": "USD",
    }
]'''

def jsonData = (new JsonSlurper()).parseText(saveDiffRateSetJsonBody)
def newRate = jsonData[0]
                
for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {

    newRate.fromcurrency = rateCurrencyList.getValue("fromCurr", i + 1) /* COL NAME, ROW */
    newRate.toCurrency = "USD"
    newRate.invConvRate = 1.09
    newRate.convRate = 1
    newRate.sourceCode = "MANUAL"
    newRate.exchangeRateSetCd = "TDM_USD_RATE_SET"
    
    jsonData[i] = newRate
}

saveDiffRateSetJsonBody = (new JsonBuilder(jsonData)).toPrettyString()

println saveDiffRateSetJsonBody
```

Result is:

```
[
    {
        "fromcurrency": "CAD",
        "invConvRate": 1.09,
        "convRate": 1,
        "sourceCode": "MANUAL",
        "tocurrency": "USD",
    },
    {
        "fromcurrency": "CAD",
        "invConvRate": 1.09,
        "convRate": 1,
        "sourceCode": "MANUAL",
        "tocurrency": "USD",
    }
]
```

I'm expecting:

```
[
    {
        "fromcurrency": "EUR",
        "invConvRate": 1.09,
        "convRate": 1,
        "sourceCode": "MANUAL",
        "tocurrency": "USD",
    },
    {
        "fromcurrency": "CAD",
        "invConvRate": 1.09,
        "convRate": 1,
        "sourceCode": "MANUAL",
        "tocurrency": "USD",
    }
]
```

I can do this multiple more object and all the object parameters will be the same. I will add that I will be doing this to more complex Json body with multiple arrays, parameters and objects but I wanted to pick a specific array/object/parameter and modify it accordingly. So basically, I will have a source body for a default parameter and use that to create a new JSON body to use for the new request.

Comment: You only have one `newRate` object/instance which you change each time - each time you add with `jsonData[i] = newRate`, it's the same instance which you update each time (thus updating all previous `jsonData[i]`)

Comment: Put `def newRate = jsonData[i]` inside the loop.

Comment: oh I see, It does make sense if all jsonData elements is linked to the object newRate.
It seems like putting def newRate = jsonData[i] does not work on groovy script as it throws me a null at i = 0. Do I need to declare an array of newRate and then add jsonData[0] in it, modify and finally append to the existing json body? I will be back and test some scenario if it will work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't quite figure how to use array or define newRate directly to jsonData inside the loop it always put me back to my original problem.
`def newRateArr = []`
`for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) { newRateArr.push(jsonData [0]) // modify newRateArr[i] }`
will put me with the same issue same with `def newRate = jsonData[0]`

using below works but I'm not quite sure if this is the right approach.
`for(int i = 0; i < rows ; i++) {
def newRateString = (new JsonBuilder(jsonData[0])).toPrettyString()
def newRateObj = (new JsonSlurper()).parseText(newRateString)
...
jsonData[i] = newRateObj
}`

Answer (score 0):

the issue was identified in comments of the question.

you are changing the same object `newRate` and adding it twice into result array.

you can define Map (aka json object) directly in a code like this:

```
def obj = [
   key1: "value1",
   "complex-key2": "value2"
]
```

serializing it to json will give you

```
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "complex-key2": "value2"
}
```

so your code could be simplified to this:

```
int rows = rateCurrencyList.getRowNumbers() /* not being used yet to iterate to all records */
def jsonData = [] //empty array
                
for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
    def newRate = [
        fromcurrency: rateCurrencyList.getValue("fromCurr", i + 1), /* COL NAME, ROW */
        toCurrency: "USD",
        invConvRate = 1.09,
        convRate: 1,
        sourceCode: "MANUAL",
        exchangeRateSetCd: "TDM_USD_RATE_SET",
    ]
    jsonData.add(newRate)
}

def saveDiffRateSetJsonBody = new JsonBuilder(jsonData).toPrettyString()

println saveDiffRateSetJsonBody
```